# Aggregate rdb and hdb in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a standard tickerplant set up with my rdb on port 5011 and hdb on port 5012. Is there an elegant way handle queries to a union of today and historical data? I am open to a union process that maintains connections to both 5011 and 5012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say this function lives on the an independant q instance and you want all columns, for a day d + today for sym s... notice the column rearrangement.

```
mergeFun:{[d;s]
    rdb:hopen`::5011;
    hdb:hopen`::5012;
    t:hdb({[d;s] `time`sym xcols delete date from select from table where date=d, sym=s};d;s),rdb({[s] select from table where sym=s};s);
    hclose each rdb,hdb;
    t
}
```

Comment: Do you think there is an advantage to opening and closing the connection inside the function call, as opposed to passing in or using a global handle?

Comment: depends how often you call it... if you keep it as a global you'll need to maintenance like .z.pc to monitor closures and reopen as necessary. If not called often, it's better to keep inside the function - that way the function will error if the r/hdb are down.

Answer (score 1):

A gateway/union process would be a good solution. See examples in Michael McClintocks whitepaper:
http://www.firstderivatives.com/lecture_series_pp.asp?downloadflyer=q_for_Gods_May_2013

Though the whitepaper possibly goes into more detail than you need, even the most basic setup from the paper would suffice. Essentially just queries rdb (and adds "missing" date col) and queries hdb and then combines the result.

Comment: This is a good reference, I often find the FD paper's very useful, thanks